# In Ruby, how do I find all the letters after the last number in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have a string with letters and numbers, something like

```
str = "123abc234abb"
```

How do I find all the letters occurring after the last number in the string?  For example, if I applied the function to the above, it would yield

```
abb
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please, show us your code, and tell us *exactly* what is wrong with it: all error messages, all warnings, what results you expect and what results you get instead.

Comment: what do you expect the function to return when handed a string with no numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookbehind:

```
"123abc234abb"[/(?<=\d)?[a-zA-Z]+\z/]
#=> "abb"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 str.rpartition(/\d+/).last
```

How does this work?

- `rpartition` splits the string into three parts, using reverse matching
- `last` picks the post-match part from the three results